# Checking object with instanceof + casting object vs overriding the method?

Tags: java

Hey I am working on a game engine and I have a few types of entites and *Monster* is one of them - it implements the *Entity* class. Inside the *Entity* class I have these methods

```
public boolean isMonter() {
    return this instanceof Monster;
}

public Monster getMonster() {
    if(iMonster()) {
        return (Monster) this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However I am wondering if it's more efficient to Override these methods inside the Monster class such as this, or does it make no difference?.

```
@Override
public boolean isMonter() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Monster getMonster() {
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to override them at all? In `isMonster()` it will be `instanceof Monster` so it will return true

Comment: Yes but I am wondering if it's more efficient to do the latter one?

Comment: the best way to answer this question is to test it.  however, even if there is a big difference, this is likely to be such a small part of your overall performance that i seriously doubt that it will be noticeable when you look at the big picture.

Comment: Yes.  It'll almost certainly be more efficient.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Since you're not actually getting something from the object, but instead returning an extended view of the object, a better name would be `asMonster()`. --- See also [What's the difference between “to” and “as” method name prefixes?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/352157/202153)